# Page won't load after MySQL query returns?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a quick question that doesn't quite make sense to me. I am a bit new to MySQL and PHP so I might just be missing something. Here's my code:

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'Josh', '**********', '********');
if ($conn->connect_error)
  die('Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error);
$result = $conn->query('SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM users WHERE id = 1');
$f = $result->fetch_array();
if ($f->cnt == 0) {
    echo 'doesn\'t exist';
} else if ($f->cnt == 1){
    echo 'does exist';
}
```

As you may be able to tell, this checks if an `id` in the table exists. If it does, it echos `'does exist'`, otherwise, it echos `'doesn't exist'`. However, I'm having a slight problem. Whenever I replace `id = 1` with an `id` that doesn't exist, it loads instantly and echoes `'doesn't exist'`. However, when I use an id that does exist in the table, the page loads but still echoes `'doesn't exist'`.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since id is an integer we can write the query in following way:

```
$result = $conn->query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = 1');
if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
    echo 'doesn\'t exist';
} else {
    echo 'does exist';
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that didn't fix it.

Comment: What happened for the above fix? can you explain more about the issue happened with the above code?

Comment: Do you mean your fix or the person above you? With your fix, the same issue occured, nothing seemed to change (when the record does exist, the page will not load, otherwise it will load and echo `doesn't exist`)

Comment: I hope you can check the connection is created or not with the following:
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . $conn->connect_error);
}
If the connection is successfully created then i feel the result will come surely.

Comment: The connection is created

Comment: I have checked in my local too i could be able to run the above code, check with apache log.In case of any errors you can find and fix it there.

Comment: When the id existed the page loaded?

Comment: Oh huh, I found the reason it's taking so long to load: http://i.imgur.com/0CQ9EQJ.png

Comment: is the query running inside the loop?

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. I had a variable named $result and there was a while loop going through it, but then inside of the loop it was setting result to the new query, so it was like an infinite loop.

Comment: Ok Then the solution is found. Super!

Answer (score 0):

I've modified it, try it.

```
$result = $conn->query('SELECT count(id) as cnt FROM users WHERE id = 1'); // or count(*)
$f = $result->fetch_object(); // or use fetch_array(),fetch_assoc() [Search the diff b/w them]
if ($f->cnt == 0) {
    echo 'doesn\'t exist';
} else {
    echo 'does exist';
}
```

**Non-Object Oriented Approach**

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'Josh', '**********', '********');

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  die('Connection failed: ' . mysqli_connect_error);

$result = mysqli_query($conn,'SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM users WHERE id = 1');

$f = mysqli_fetch_array($result); // or mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
echo $f['cnt'];
if ($f['cnt'] == 0) {
    echo 'doesn\'t exist';
} else if ($f['cnt'] == 1){
    echo 'does exist';
}
```

Comment: That fixes the page loading bug, but now it doesn't echo anything.

Comment: did you try `count(*)`?.. and also, first test your query in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Here's what appeared in PhpMyAdmin http://i.imgur.com/kh7gvHn.png, and yes, I did try `count(*)` but it did not work.

Comment: That's the correct result you should get by your query. try the different functions of fetching results as mentioned in the comment in line2

Comment: test if the result is being stored in `$f` or not by echoing it just before the if statement. `echo $f->cnt;`.... also check your database connections.

Comment: Oh, now it echoed `doesn't exist` (which is correct), then I changed the id to 1 (which does exist) and it still echoed `doesn't exist`.

Comment: Does the same thing as before except it's cnt is 1 rather than 0

Comment: remove 'else' and add `else if($f->cnt == "1")`.. also try after putting the 0 in quotes.

Comment: Update your question with the full code including connections

Comment: Why the password and database name are **********?

Comment: Oh, that's for privacy.

Comment: Okay, I don't find any lack in your code. try non-object oriented method. I'll update my answer with that.

Comment: Modified it. Check it out.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I found what was causing the page to not load. Again, thank you a LOT for helping me.

Comment: Welcome...What was the problem?

Comment: I was looping through a variable named result, and then I set the variable result inside of it, so it was like an infinite loop